# CN1 server compile fails with Could not find method compile() for arguments [{name=ZBarScannerLibrary, ext=aar}]

Tags: codenameone, zbar

I was trying to compile my app on the server and I get the following;

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/tmp/build1488715586743084148xxx/DrinkQuCustApp/build.gradle' line: 69
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'DrinkQuCustApp'.

  > Could not find method compile() for arguments [{name=ZBarScannerLibrary, ext=aar}] on DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.braintreepayments.api', name='drop-in', version='3.+', configuration='default'}.

I do have two hints;

```
android.xapplication = <activity android:name="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:label="@string/app_name" /><activity android:name="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:label="@string/app_name" tools:replace="android:label" />

android.xpermissions = <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/><uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

The code compiles locally. It has been a while, but I think the previous code with the scanner is compiled.

Comment: Provide a link to the `error.txt` file.

Comment: Seems like links to Braintree and/or it's dependencies repository are broken.

Comment: I am not sure what that means, where to look, or how to fix it?

Comment: You are using Braintree library, right?

Comment: Yes. I tried refreshing the CN1 libraries. I also removed the build hints and code that references the scanner and Braintree code. Relatively new to NetBeans/CN1, so not sure how to remove the braintree libraries.

Comment: Can you provide the link for the full error log?

Comment: Do you have access to this locations?
 https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/d600833f-4325-4446-9d49-05658c83bbd7-1509155512993-error.txt